# Texture Baking cuse problems

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-baking

Im stuck with this issue for several days now. and i have no idea what the hell to do with it.
i moddled a tie fighter, and i make Procedural texture.

now im trying to bake the roughness. and i get several problems:

first off: i get this weird black spots all over the Seems. i checked the normal's and they completely i have no idea why the heck this is happening.

the only i was able to get it fixed so far is too export the object as FBX and append it along witht he matirial to a new project.
(witch i would have done. but that require Unrawpp every component of the Tie fighter. and if if want to pack the island properly its gonna make a problems.

2: i tried to fix this with the clone tool and in the texture paint mode but for some reasons the painted texture. look less contrasted then the original witch makes it very noticeable.

3:for some reason the texture from the baked result look different.

it looks less dense and somewhat bigger then the procedural one: why?

im literaly pooling my hair out. so far i got no explainations for this load of BS and i need to solve it. so if anyone know what the hell to do please let me know?

[image]

Comment: Those spots kind of look like the shape of little groups of quads. Any chance there are  any duplicate or flipped faces in those areas?

Comment: nope. 
one of the first things i did, was to check the normals.
and some of those points are not on areas i edited so there is no duplicate vertices.

Comment: Dark areas like that usually mean there is geometry occluding the bake. Whether or not you think there is duplicate faces involved, there is either something in the object level or a separate object that intersects the surface of the object being baked.

Comment: sorry for the delayed. 
it was already suggested in a differense. i tried to change the object into local vew. but it didnt help.

oddly enough it was solved when i kept the object with only one material and then did the baking again (it has two matirials on it) why did it happen?

i have no idea.